# Preventing td from getting smaller when content is empty

Tags: html

I have the following table structure. I have a table inside a table here.

[image]

My issue is, if the td doesnt contain any text, the full-height gets removed for some reason:

[image]

This is my HTML: (mixed with some Razor which isnt really relevant here)

```
<td style="padding:0;margin:0;"class="border border-dark border-dark">
                    <table class=" table-borderless justify-content-center " cellspacing="20" style="height:100%!important;padding:0;margin:0;">
                        <tr style="height:100%; text-align:center;font-size:10px;"class="flex-none">
                                            if (condition)
                                            {
                                                <td style="width:@Percent%; height:100%;" onclick="document.getElementById('EventId_HiddenInput').value='@Model.Events.SingleOrDefault(r => r.EventId == id).EventId';" class="FillModalWithEventData bg-primary flex-md-fill">
                                                    <a onclick="document.getElementById('EventId_HiddenInput').value='@Model.Events.SingleOrDefault(r => r.EventId == id).EventId';" class="FillModalWithEventData">@Model.Events.SingleOrDefault(r => r.EventId == id).Company.ToString()</a>
                                                </td>

                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <td style="width:@Percent%;height:100%; " onclick="document.getElementById('EventId_HiddenInput').value='@Model.Events.SingleOrDefault(r => r.EventId == id).EventId';" class="FillModalWithEventData bg-primary ">
                                                    <a onclick="document.getElementById('EventId_HiddenInput').value='@Model.Events.SingleOrDefault(r => r.EventId == id).EventId';" class="FillModalWithEventData">filler</a>

                                                </td>
                                            }

                            <td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
```

How can I prevent it from shrinking and keep it at full height if td is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You should set height 100% and display: inline-block; for a.
But then the text will run up, but if you want to have it in the middle, then the solution for you is:

```
display: flex;
height: 100%;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Or set some height for td in px, vh, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to add a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) inside those empty cells.

A CSS solution would look like this:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
}

tr:not(:last-child) td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

td::before,
td::after {
  content: '\00a0'; /* Escaped Unicode representation of a non-breaking space */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```